# Could not open input file: D:\xampp\phalcon-devtools\phalcon.php

Tags: php, phalcon

Instalé todo correcto, pero no encuentro el archivo `.php` y veo la carpeta y tampoco la trae,¿qué pasó?

Las variables de entorno estan correctas, `phpinfo()` me muestra que si tengo `phalcon`

Pero al ejecutarlo me muestra este error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2):

Estas pueden ser algunas posibles correciones.

> - Instalar phalcon
> - Clonar phalcon-devtools Establezca los permisos y
> - Ejecute `phalcon.bat`  Agregue el directorio `c: \ phalcon-devtools a    PATH (es decir, c: \ phalcon-devtools)`

Finalmente vuelva a ejecutar:

```
phalcon
```

Para más información visite la [Documentación](https://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/wintools.html)